# adding subviews to UITableViewCell issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableView , in which if I tap on one of the rows it adds a subview at the bottom. The issue is that when I tap the last row in the table, it hides the subviews and having me to scroll to the bottom to see it. It's a small bug, but what is the best way to remedy this issue.

One way I can think of is to scroll down to the bottom of the row if the last row is selected.
This doesn't seem to be a very good solution though.

Here's a [video](http://www.screenr.com/CXI) illustrating my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something like this in the didSelectRow method:

```
if (indexPath.row == [dataArray count]) {
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row
                                                       inSection:0]
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                           animated:YES];   
}
```

I've also used the following for making the last row visible (though from your video I do not think this will work for your situation)

```
[guessesTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Yeah, you want it to auto-scroll to bring the selected row fully into view.  The above code looks about right.

Comment: that's actually my solution, wonder if there's other way than that

Comment: and it should be [dataArray count]-1, the row are 0 indexed

Comment: About the only other thing you can do is adjust the above algorithm so that any row touched (or at least one below the bottom 1/3rd or so) is raised to about the 1/3rd from the bottom point.  This may be a bit more "intuitive"/less "jolting" (though you have to be the judge).  Similar techniques are used when touching something produces a keyboard popup.